# Ingress Controller produces 502 Bad Gateway on every other request

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, kubernetes, aws-elb

I have a kubernetes ingress controller terminating my ssl with an ingress resource handling two routes: 1 my frontend SPA app, and the second backend api. Currently when I hit each frontend and backend service directly they perform flawlessly, but when I call the ingress controller both frontend and backend services alternate between producing the correct result and a 502 Bad Gateway.

To me it smells like my ingress resource is having some sort of path conflict that I'm not sure how to debug.

[Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/kubernetes/comments/oaxarg/intermittent_502_bad_gateway_issue/) suggested that it could be a label and selector mismatch between my services and deployments which I believe I checked thoroughly. they also mentioned: "api layer deployment and a worker layer deployment [that] both share a common app label and your PDB selects that app label with a 50% availability for example". Which I haven't run down because I don't quite understand.

I also realize SSL could play a role in gateway issues; However, my certificates appear to be working when I hit the https:// port of the ingress-controller

frontend-deploy:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: frontend
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-performance-front
      tier: frontend
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-performance-front
        tier: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my-performance-frontend
          image: "<my current image and location>"
          lifecycle:
            preStop:
              exec:
                command: ["/usr/sbin/nginx","-s","quit"]
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred
```

frontend-svc

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: frontend
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-performance-front
    tier: frontend
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  type: LoadBalancer
```

backend-deploy

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: backend
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-performance-back
      tier: backend
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-performance-back
        tier: backend
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my-performance-backend
          image: "<my current image and location>"
          lifecycle:
            preStop:
              exec:
                command: ["/usr/sbin/nginx","-s","quit"]
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred
```

backend-svc

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: backend
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-performance-back
    tier: backend
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      name: "http"
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
  type: LoadBalancer
```

ingress-rules

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-rules
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/$1"
#    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/service-upstream: "true"
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /(api/v0(?:/|$).*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: backend
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: frontend
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Any ideas, critiques, or experiences are welcomed and appreciated!!!

Comment: Could you check frontend and backed pod logs, and include those in the question? It's possible it's an issie with the app itself.

Comment: I can provide them, what are you looking for specifically? When I hit the services themselves they work perfectly.

Comment: Any indication that application rejected a request. Only thing that comes to my mind is that `(api/v0(?:/|$).*)` is getting caught by `(.*)` and requests to backend are sent to the frontend. If that's the case, you may try using `pathType: Exact`.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue now! Have you found out the problem by any chance?